# Llenar dataset con MongoDB y c#

Tags: c#, oracle, mongodb

¿Como puedo migrar este código de Oracle a MongoDB? Estoy usando C# y la idea es llenar el Dataset con datos de Mongo.

> Código Original

```
    private DataSet datos()
    {
        DataSet dataSet;
        OracleCommand oracleCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
        DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet("empDataSet");
        try
        {
            OracleDataAdapter oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
             conn.Open();

            oracleCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from table";
            oracleDataAdapter.set_SelectCommand(oracleCommand);
            oracleDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet1, "EmployeesData2");
            oracleCommand.Dispose();
            oracleDataAdapter.Dispose();
            return dataSet1;
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        { dataSet = null;       }
        return dataSet;
    }
```

> Mis Avances:

```
 protected static IMongoClient clienteLocal = new MongoClient();
  protected static IMongoDatabase dataLocal = clienteLocal.GetDatabase("database");
  var tabla = dataLocal.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("tabla");
            var filtro = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
            var cursor = tabla.Find(filtro);
            var listado = cursor.ToList();
            foreach (var item in listado)
            {                    
             //Se sopone que ya esta listo el query para mostrar todos los datos existentes, pero como se llena el data?' o existe alguna manera equivalente
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes una entidad podrias convetirla a datatable con la ayuda de 
**CopyToDataTable**

[Creating a DataTable From a Query (LINQ to DataSet)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921(v=vs.110).aspx)

Analiza la seccion "Creating a Custom CopyToDataTable Method" veras que es simple de utilizar